# .split() function doubt

Tags: python

Here is a line of code

```py
str(x).split(' ')[-1][1:]
```

The `split` function within its parenthesis has `' '`.
Is it necessary, or we can also leave the split function with no arguments like

`str(x).split()[-1][1:]`

I think both works in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

If the characters in `x` are separated by spaces, they work the same way. If there are multiple whitespaces between the chacacters, they work differently as `str(x).split(' ')` splits specifically by each space and `str(x).split()` splits by consecutive whitespace.

Example:

```py
test_cases = ["a b c", "a   b   c"]
for x in test_cases:
    splitted_by_space = x.split(" ")
    splitted_by_consecutive_ws = x.split()
    print("x =", '"' + x + '"')
    print('x.split(" ") -->',  splitted_by_space)
    print('x.split()    -->',  splitted_by_consecutive_ws)
    print("-" * 50)
```

Output:

```
x = "a b c"
x.split(" ") --> ['a', 'b', 'c']
x.split()    --> ['a', 'b', 'c']
--------------------------------------------------
x = "a   b   c"
x.split(" ") --> ['a', '', '', 'b', '', '', 'c']
x.split()    --> ['a', 'b', 'c']
--------------------------------------------------
```

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> `str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`
>   
>   *If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a `None` separator returns `[]`.*